# How to make a bump app in android?

Tags: android, bump

I would like to add a bump feature in my app in android but since its gaining momnentum now only,I couldn't get a proper implementation pattern for it.Any expertise on it,please help me with your valuable suggestions.Thanks

Comment: +1 for asking about uncommon features.

Comment: Could you define what "bump feature" is? I'm sorry, but I don't know :( - Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Bump Technologies Bump API http://bu.mp/api

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad.

First : the newer phones may have NFC support. So you have to learn [How to NFC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49L7z3rxz4Q)

Second : In the case that the phones don't have NFC, you'll have to do with GPS and the gryo sensor based information. To improve the algo, you should consider using Bearing, Altitude etc.

Comment: Using a GPS algo to match devices will infringe Bump's Patent.